# What happens when the plate of an electrophorus is touched more than a short duration?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, coulombs-law

In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sqhgrw3bDmU) it is said that in an [electrophorus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrophorus) by putting a finger on the plate, negative charge is taken off. Also, it is said that between the plate and the cake, no current flows, as on a "microcopic level" there is still a little gap between them. However, if we do not remove the finger, which draws negative charge continuously, would that not imply that the plate gets more and more positive. Hence, at a certain point a current flow should start (or at least a lightning)? Is this right? Hence, for the working it is essential that the plate is not touched too long?